# Visual Studio 2017 15.3 Simplifying null check

Tags: c#, null, visual-studio-2017

I have this code:

```
public UnityResolver(IUnityContainer container)
{
   if (container == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
   _container = container;
}
```

Visual Studio shows 3 grey dots and suggests to simplify the null check.

It makes the method this:

```
_container = container ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
```

That don't build...

What's going on here? Why does it think it can simplify this and why is it simplifying it to something that doesn't build.

The error is gives is:

```
1>L:\SL1-(SentiLAN)-SentiLAN v1 - Current System\SentilanCore\WEB API with Plugins\APITest2\App_Start\UnityConfig.cs(31,39,31,44): error CS1525: Invalid expression term 'throw'
1>L:\SL1-(SentiLAN)-SentiLAN v1 - Current System\SentilanCore\WEB API with Plugins\APITest2\App_Start\UnityConfig.cs(31,39,31,44): error CS1002: ; expected
```

[image]

Comment: _container = container ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("container"); should build properly. looks like valid code

Comment: How are you building? That's an odd error message format for Visual Studio. My guess is that whatever build process you're using is still using a C# 6 compiler.

Comment: @Jon Skeet. I'm building using VS2017 and hitting F5. Interestingly no error show in the error window but the 2 errors show in the output window under Build.

Comment: @DavidG. I installed unity and Unity.WebAPI via nuget, how does this effect the compiler I use? (I'm using hte Unity DependencyInjection framework not the game engine thing).

Comment: @Stuart Yeah, ignore me :)

Comment: @Stuart I am confident of my answer don't ignore me  :)

Comment: I'm not ignoring you, I appreciate the answer and I'm updating now. I'll let you know what happens!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its a compiler issue, code is valid. they updated the version and fixed the error in the latest update(few hours ago). you can download the update if the notification pops up or from the website.

Or simply update the Microsoft compiler version, since it wasn't included in the VS 2017...

`Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Compilers -Version 2.3.0` is the latest i think

Comment: Trying this now:)

Comment: Same error after updating. The nuget install went fine too.

Comment: look at this [thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/28293/throw-expression-causes-compiler-error-cs1525.html) seems exactly same as your issue